# want to get all files from device storage

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

for getting all files in passing different extensions. Is there a way to get all extensions files from the file

```
  files = await fm.filesTree(excludedPaths: [
  "/storage/emulated/0/Android"
], extensions: [
  "jpg",
  "jpeg",
  "jfif",
  "png",
  "zip",
  "mp3",
]
```

Comment: It is hard to understand your question. What does this even mean: "... get all extensions files from the file." ? Can you please clarify what you mean? One suggestion is with some clear examples on expected input and expected output.

Comment: actually i want to get files from file manager device/device storage so for that i use mp3 for getting mp3 files zip for getting zip files. and i want to get all files from device like mp3,mp4,img,vedio,zip, All files.. so is there a way to get all files directly instead of using extensions of every file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `extensions:` property.

```
files = await fm.filesTree(excludedPaths: ["/storage/emulated/0/Android"])
```

When you add the `extensions` property, then you add a filter to only allow those. If you remove it (or set it to null), then all files are added.

Comment: thank you and if i want to get all folders  and also user can open each folder like a file manager.?

Comment: New questions => Separate questions in StackOverflow :) Keep questions precise (and preferable small) means that more people will find your question helpful.